# Python, checking data file for certain lines

Tags: python, counter, readline

I've never taken a class that used python, just c, c++, c#, java, etc..
This should be easy but I'm feeling like I'm missing something huge that python reacts to.
All I'm doing is reading in a file, checking for lines that are only digits, counting how many lines like that and displaying it.

So I'm opening, reading, striping, checking isdigit(), and incrementing. What's wrong?

```
# variables
sum = 0
switch = "run"

print( "Reading data.txt and counting..." )

# open the file
file = open( 'data.txt', 'r' )

# run through file, stripping lines and checking for numerics, incrementing sum when neeeded
while ( switch == "run" ):
    line = file.readline()
    line = line.strip()

    if ( line.isdigit() ):
        sum += 1

    if ( line == "" ):
        print( "End of file\ndata.txt contains %s lines of digits" %(sum) )
        switch = "stop"
```

Comment: Well, for one, your indentation seems to be broken but that's probably just due to the formatting. What kind of error are you getting? And by the way, not having taken a class in something means nothing in this world.

Comment: The indentation is just how it came out here.
With this code, it's printing out 0 for sum.
And how about, I've never learned python before, better?

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but the above code stops when it hits a line of whitespace.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the lines in data.txt? I tried the code and it worked.

Comment: `sum` is a reserved keyword in Python. Please don't use it!

Comment: I really can't figure out why it isn't working, it keeps returning a 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way in Python to tell if you've reached the end of a file is *not* to see if it returns an empty line.

Instead, iterate over all the lines in the file, and the loop will end when the end of the file is reached.

```
num_digits = 0
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            num_digits += 1
```

Because files can be iterated over, you can simplify this using a generator expression:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
   num_digits = sum( 1 for line in f if line.strip().isdigit() )
```

I would also recommend against using reserved Python keywords such as `sum` as variable names, and it's also terribly inefficient to use string comparisons for flow logic like you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum=0
f=open("file")
for line in f:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
         sum+=1
f.close()
```

Comment: OP's program fails when an empty line is in the middle of the file

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the program?  Are you sure data.txt has data?  Is there an empty line in the file?

try this:

```
while 1:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line: break
    line = line.strip()

    if ( line.isdigit() ):
        sum += 1


print( "End of file\ndata.txt contains %s lines of digits" %(sum) )
```

Comment: brackets are not needed for if statement

Comment: true but i just kinda copied and pasted from the OP

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running your code:

```
matti@konata:~/tmp$ cat data.txt 
1
a
542
dfd
b
42
matti@konata:~/tmp$ python johnredyns.py 
Reading data.txt and counting...
End of file
data.txt contains 3 lines of digits
```

It works fine here. What's in your data.txt?

Comment: Did you try it on a file with a line of whitespace before the end?

Comment: senderle: Whitespace at the end shouldn't make a difference, but whitespace in the middle will correctly only count numbers coming before the line, just like OP's if statement specifies.

Comment: I guess I doubt that's the OP's intent; in that case, the output line should read `End of file\ndata.txt contains %s lines of digits before the first line of whitespace`

Answer (score 0):

As several people have said, your code appears to work perfectly.  Perhaps your "data.txt" file is in a different directory than your current working directory (not necessarily the directory that your script is in)?

However, here's a more "pythonic" way of doing the same thing:

```
counter = 0
with open('data.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            counter += 1
print 'There are a total of {0} lines that start with digits'.format(counter)
```

You could even make it a one-liner with:

```
counter = sum([line.strip().isdigit() for line in open('data.txt', 'r')])
```

I'd avoid that route at first though... It's much less readable!

Comment: Quick note, the question was to count lines that are only composed of digits, not those that start with one. Just a matter of removing [0] in the code though.

Comment: @squiddy Woops, quite right! I misread it, thanks! For some reason I read the question as "lines that start with a digit"... (Reposting comment, as I accidentally deleted it a moment ago...)